MPC Controller Tuning
Brief:
The key objective I have been working under is to make the vehicle to follow and align the path most accurately possible and the other objective is to avoid the obstacle which is in the path and again align to the original path to reach the goal
I'm currently working on tuning a Model Predictive Controller (MPC) for a robotic vehicle with Ackermann steering (4m length, 1m width). My primary goal is to ensure accurate path-following, where the vehicle aligns with the planned path, avoids obstacles effectively, and returns to the original path to reach its goal. The setup includes ROS 2 with the nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController plugin configured for Ackermann motion models, and I've implemented several specific critics to guide navigation decisions, such as path-following, obstacle avoidance, and goal alignment.
Problem
I’m facing significant issues with path adherence, especially during turns or when following curved paths. The vehicle tends to deviate from the path considerably, failing to realign smoothly. Additionally, in obstacle avoidance scenarios, the vehicle approaches obstacles very closely and struggles to stay on its path. In some cases, it even pauses for extended periods upon nearing an obstacle, disrupting the flow of motion and impacting goal completion.
System Configuration & Parameters
The controller operates at 20 Hz, with various parameters like a minimum turning radius of 5.0, a maximum speed of 1.0 m/s, and a collision margin distance of 0.1m. The critics configured include constraints for path alignment, obstacle handling, goal orientation, and more, each with specific weights and cost metrics. I have tested this setup in Gazebo and Rviz, and observed that, although the path is visually represented accurately, the actual vehicle trajectory deviates significantly (visible in red)image reference in docs, especially around obstacles and on curves.
How can I adjust my MPC settings or critic configurations to improve path-following, particularly around curves and in tight obstacle scenarios, while minimizing unnecessary stops?
Any suggestions on specific parameter adjustments or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
I Clearly Mentioned all the details(code,version i'm using,Problem statement) in the Docs link below

Hello, there is access approvement required to the document you've posted. Specyfing all information in the post would make easier to help with your issue.

I specified all the information in the post
